# While updating firebase crashlytics getting below issue

Tags: crashlytics

while updating  com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics getting this issue

update the firebase-crashlytics  with one signal

Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Versions that do not match:

- 1.2.2
- 1.2.1
- 1.2.0
- 1.1.0
- 1.0.2
- - 2 more
    Required by:

  project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0

Android Need to update the fire base crashlytics we are using one signal also please let me know any solution

Could not find any version that matches com.google.firebase:firebase-sessions:[15.0.0, 16.0.0).
Versions that do not match:

- 1.2.2
- 1.2.1
- 1.2.0
- 1.1.0
- 1.0.2
- - 2 more
    Required by:

  project :app > com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.4.0

Comment: Can you share your build.gradle file? Also, what are you trying to do? How does OneSignal relate to Crashlytics?